# do same function for every element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have s Small issue
first : i want to add a new td and tr autamticly when i press button
second : i want to apply he same function to show menue when i clcik on any input of these
and i am sorry for this i am a Junior
i know that i should not repeat id name for the element but i don't know what to do
i made snippet

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#input");
const menue = document.querySelector(".menue");

input.addEventListener("click", function() {
  menue.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
.dropdown {
  width: 180px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
}

.menue {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  border: blue;
  background-color: lightgray;
  z-index: 1;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
      <td>
        <tr>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="search_input">
              <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="search" onclick="">
            </div>
            <div class="menue">
              <p>html</p>
              <p>CSS</p>
              <p>js</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </tr>
      </td>

      <td>
        <tr>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="search_input">
              <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="search">
            </div>
            <div class="menue">
              <p>html</p>
              <p>CSS</p>
              <p>js</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </tr>
      </td>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
  </table>
  <button>add new row</button>
  <script src="/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'd first make your HTML valid: `<td>` elements cannot have `<tr>` as children. You got that inverted.

Comment: You can use class instead of id for referencing the element and attach a handler using event delegation approach (see duplicate question).

Comment: well thanks : but you can help me ? i saw the link  above about DOM event delegation .. but  the examplese not simlar to mine here  .. if you can help me by code and i will learn it and understand it just put me in the way

Comment: can you edit my code in snippet or somthing ?